# asyncio yield from concurrent.futures.Future of an Executor

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

I have a `long_task` function which runs a heavy cpu-bound calculation and I want to make it asynchronous by using the new asyncio framework. The resulting `long_task_async` function uses a `ProcessPoolExecutor` to offload work to a different process to not be constrained by the GIL.

The trouble is that for some reason the `concurrent.futures.Future` instance returned from `ProcessPoolExecutor.submit` when yielded from throws a `TypeError`. Is this by design? Are those futures not compatible with `asyncio.Future` class? What would be a workaround?

I also noticed that generators are not picklable so submitting a couroutine to the `ProcessPoolExecutor` is going to fail. Is there any clean solution to this as well?

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

@asyncio.coroutine
def long_task():
    yield from asyncio.sleep(4)
    return "completed"

@asyncio.coroutine
def long_task_async():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(1) as ex:
        return (yield from ex.submit(long_task)) #TypeError: 'Future' object is not iterable
                                                 # long_task is a generator, can't be pickled

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

@asyncio.coroutine
def main():
    n = yield from long_task_async()
    print( n )

loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to use [`loop.run_in_executor`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executor), which uses a `concurrent.futures` executor, but maps the return value to an `asyncio` future.

The original `asyncio` PEP [suggests that](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/#futures) `concurrent.futures.Future` may someday grow a `__iter__` method so it can be used with `yield from` as well, but for now the library has been designed to only require `yield from` support and nothing more.  (Otherwise some code wouldn't actually work in 3.3.)

Answer (score 12):

We can wrap a `concurrent.futures.Future` into an `asyncio.future` by calling `asyncio.wrap_future(Future)`. I tried it with the below code. Works fine

```
from asyncio import coroutine
import asyncio
from concurrent import futures


def do_something():
    ls = []
    for i in range(1, 1000000):
        if i % 133333 == 0:
            ls.append(i)
    return ls


@coroutine
def method():
    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        job = executor.submit(do_something)
        return (yield from asyncio.wrap_future(job))

@coroutine
def call_method():
    result = yield from method()
    print(result)


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(call_method())
    finally:
        loop.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```